# Проблемы с TimeZone при подключении MySQL к intelijiIdea

Tags: java, mysql, sql, база-данных, intellij-idea

Создал пустой проект в intelijiIdea "Hello, Word", решил подключиться к серверу через боковую панельку DataBase -> + -> Data Source -> MySQL.
Данные для подключения ввел верные: и пароль, и пользователя и название БД.
При тестовом подключении выдает ошибку ТаймЗоны, решил и ее настроить, в той же панельке для подключения в разделе OPTIONS для поля Time Zone пробовал прописать и UTC и Europe/Moscow. Ничего не помогает.

Вот что выдает при тест.подключении:

```java
ava.lang.RuntimeException: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.InvalidConnectionAttributeException: The server time zone value 'RTZ 2 (çèìà)' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:85)
    at com.mysql.cj.util.TimeUtil.getCanonicalTimezone(TimeUtil.java:132)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.configureTimezone(NativeProtocol.java:2241)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.initServerSession(NativeProtocol.java:2265)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializePropsFromServer(ConnectionImpl.java:1319)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:868)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:830)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:455)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:240)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:199)
    in JdbcHelperImpl.connect(JdbcHelperImpl.java:563) (no stack trace).
com.mysql.cj.exceptions.InvalidConnectionAttributeException: The server time zone value 'RTZ 2 (çèìà)' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
```

Саму БД создал в WorkBench.

P.S. Я пробовал некоторые варианты со stackoverflow, но все без изменений.

Workbench version 8.0
MySQL version 8.0
IDEA version 2019.1.3
Java version 12.02

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Знакомая тема.
Зайди в Workbench и экзекьютни `set global time_zone = '-3:00';` Теперь должно подключаться

Comment: Отлично, два дня голову ломал!

Answer (score 5):

В URL при подключении к БД добавь `serverTimezone=Europe/Moscow`

Пример:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springTest?serverTimezone=Europe/Moscow
```

Comment: На практике не проверил, так как вариант с первым ответом уже сработал! Спасибо