# Ошибка при подключении к MYSQL time zone

Tags: java, spring-boot

> java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value 'RTZ 9 (çèìà)' is
>   unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure
>   either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration
>   property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize
>   time zone support.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Проблемы с TimeZone при подключении MySQL к intelijiIdea](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1021787/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d1%81-timezone-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-mysql-%d0%ba-intelijiidea)

Comment: Благодарю за наводку. Ответ уже мной был дан, спасибо за уделенное внимание.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам поначалу недельку голову ломал. Зайди в Workbench и экзекьютни

```sql
 set global time_zone = '-3:00';
```

Теперь должно подключаться

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Проблему уже решил, мой вариант мне тоже подошёл.

Answer (score 0):

Это является ответом. Заменяем здесь localhost, если нужно и меняем db на свою базу данных.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/db ?useUnicode=true&serverTimezone=UTC&useSSL=true&verifyServerCertificate=false
```